# Grails: SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin

Tags: oracle, grails

When I run my app in GGTS 3.6.2 using Grails 2.4.3 I've got a message:

```
Caused by SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:port/OCI
->>  689 | getConnection in java.sql.DriverManager
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    247 | getConnection in     ''
|     18 | <init> .  in awtool.Controller
|    266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with errorJava HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```

I read many posts about this error and used some recommendations. 
I added ojdbc6.jar to project /lib
also I added ojdbc6.jar at project Java Build Path using Add External JAR..

Java and Grails PATHs is OK

Is there is a way how I can resolve this problem ?

BuildConfig.groovy:

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    // test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivymaven
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        // mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        // mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        // mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    mavenRepo "http://repo.spring.io/milestone/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34'
        // runtime "com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.4"
        // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
        test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0-grails-2.4"
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.7'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.6"
    compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"
    compile ":spring-security-ldap:2.0-RC2" 
    compile ":force-ssl:1.0.0"
        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.5" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.17"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

        // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
        //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
        //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
        //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
        //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
    }
}


grails.server.port.http=8088
```

DataSource.groovy

```
import groovy.sql.*

dataSource {
    pooled = true
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    username = "login"
    password = "pass"
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {

            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:mysql://server:port/login"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://server:port/login"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://server:port/login"

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us your `DataSource.groovy` as well as `BuildConfig.groovy`

Comment: @crudolf added to main post

Answer (score 1):

"Add External JAR.." and other ways of adding to the IDE classpath aren't useful when using Grails - the IDEs build their classpaths from the Grails dependencies, so you only need to ensure that Grails has access.

When adding jars to the lib dir (which should be avoided in general, but is needed in this case because Oracle annoyingly refuses to put their driver jars in public repos) you need to run

```
 grails compile --refresh-dependencies
```

to get it added to the classpath - Grails hasn't had auto-detection of jars in `/lib` for a while.

Once you do that, if you need the jar for compilation (you don't in this case) then refresh the IDE from Grails. In GGTS/STS you can do this by right-clicking the project root node in the tree on the left and selecting Grails Tools | Refresh Dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Burt's answer explaining how to get Grails to find your Oracle library, you need to change `DataSource.groovy` to connect to an Oracle database (it's currently configured for MySQL). You need to change it to something like:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"
    dbCreate = "update" 
    url = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:mydb'
    username = "root"
    password = "password"
    properties {
        // See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource for documentation
        jmxEnabled = false
        initialSize = 5
        maxActive = 50
        minIdle = 5
        maxIdle = 25
        maxWait = 10000
        maxAge = 10 * 60000
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
        validationQuery = "select 1 from dual"
        validationQueryTimeout = 3
        validationInterval = 15000
        testOnBorrow = true
        testWhileIdle = true
        testOnReturn = false
        jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState;StatementCache(max=200)"
        defaultTransactionIsolation = Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
    }
}
hibernate {
    flush.mode = 'manual'

    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = true
    cache.region.factory_class = "net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory"
}
```

Replace `mydb`, `root`, and `password` with the name of your schema, and the username and password you'll use to access it.

Comment: In my controllers I am using two connections: mysql and oracle. The connect described in DataSource.groovy - is a connect to database only for Domain models.